# Unable to Log Outside of app.js in an Express Application

Tags: node.js, express, routes, controller, ejs

I'm working on an Express application using Node.js, and I'm facing an issue with generating logs outside the app.js file. Here is my setup:

In my app.js file, I'm able to generate logs as expected. For example, I have a /login route where I can use console.log to display messages in the console:

```
//app.js
const express = require('express');
const db = require('./config/db');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const traningRoutes = require('./routes/traningRoutes');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');
const flash = require('connect-flash');


const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Here it works");
  res.render('login'); 
});
```

However, in my **`dashboard.js`** file (which is a controller used to handle certain routes), the **`checkLogin`** function doesn't generate logs, even though I've added logging statements:

```
// controllers/dashboard.js
const db = require('../config/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');


exports.checkLogin = () =>{
  console.log("ici ça fonctionne pas rien n'est log"); // ça ça fonctionne pas 
}
```

```
//authRoutes.js
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const dashboardController = require('../controllers/dashboardController');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/login',dashboardController.checkLogin);
```

I am using the controller-route-views architecture. Can anyone provide insights into why I can't generate logs outside of the app.js file? How can I resolve this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I want to be able to log out of my app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where my problem came from is that i wanted to create groups with /api :

```
app.use('/api', traningRoutes);
app.use('/api', authRoutes);
app.use('/api', userRoutes);
```

it block all routes so I just remove api and it works

```
app.use('/', traningRoutes);
```

And the most important things it's I have to put :

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
// Routes pour les API
app.use('/', traningRoutes); // This routes must be before 
app.use('/', authRoutes);//    app.get ('/display'){...}
app.use('/', userRoutes);//

// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to your CRM Mix Application');
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login'); 
});

app.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.render('register'); 
});

app.get('/display', (req, res) => {
  res.render('display'); 
});
```

if you put app.get before app.use it will throw

> undefined error

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to see where you can called, authRoutes in server.js that may be the first issue and secondly checkLogin will be called when you hit the /login API, hope you are doing that.

Comment: I called here : app.use('/api', authRoutes); in app.js

and In my login.ejs : <body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="/api/login" method="POST">
        <label for="email">Email :</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" required>
        <label for="password">Password :</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>

It's very weird because in app.js it works but when I tried to use with this architecture it didn't work

Comment: So your issue is your routes are not properly routed, Is authRoutes.js returning router?